# JavaScript RegEx: Return true if any part of keyword string matches value in array

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having a heck of a time getting a simple regex working. I hate regex :(

I have an array of TV channel names that I need to compare against the value coming from a search field.  If any part of the search text matches, then it passes. Else it fails.

So searching for `"dis"` should pass for:
`"Discovery Channel"`, `"Disney Channel"`, `"24 Hour Disco"`, etc.

How might one do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for regex, this:

```
var data = ["Discovery Channel", "Disney Channel", "24 Hour Disco", "foo", "bar", "fail"];
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i].toLowerCase().indexOf('dis') !== -1) {
        console.log(data[i]);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Discovery Channel
Disney Channel
24 Hour Disco
```

---

Of course, you can always use regex. Replace:

```
data[i].toLowerCase().indexOf('dis') !== -1
```

With this:

```
data[i].match(/dis/i)
```

---

***Update:***

For the regex solution...if `'dis'` is contained in a variable, you can construct a `RegExp` object directly:

```
var pattern = 'dis';
var regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'i');

data[i].match(regex);
```

Comment: @sam How do i get the /dis/ out of a variable into a valid regex format?

Comment: Not sure I'm following you, @Ben.

Comment: you wrote `data[i].match(/dis/i)`.  I need to do this: `data[i].match(/myVar/i)` but don't know proper syntax.

Answer (score 5):

You could do it with `filter` and `match` like this:

```js
var channels = ["Discovery Channel", "Disney Channel", "24 Hour Disco", "CNN"];

var filter = function(channel) { 
    return channel.match(/dis/i); 
};

alert(channels.filter(filter));
```

If you have to pass your query part, you could call function like this:

```js
var channels = ["Discovery Channel", "Disney Channel", "24 Hour Disco", "CNN"];

var filter = function(term) {     
    return function(channel) {
        return channel.match(new RegExp(term, "i")); 
    }
};

alert(channels.filter(filter('dis')));
```

Comment: Now I feel stupid for not using `.filter()`. Personally (if I were OP), I would use a combination of your filter and my non-regex.

Comment: `.filter()` and `.map()` are my favourite functions :)